# Uniform value is wrong in adreno 305 qualcom device but right in Adreno Profiler

Tags: android, graphics, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

I´m doing my own game engine. Now, the next step is to build my fragment shader for multiple lighting sources. 
I found a very strange behaviour I can't understand. In my Moto G 2014 with an 305 Adreno video chip a glsl length function call gives me an incorrect value over a ambient lighting uniform, resulting in wrong scene lighting.
Let's see for fist the fragment code:

```
#define numLights x
#pragma glsl

precision lowp float;

struct LightSourceParameters {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 lightColor;
    vec4 position;
    float spotExponent;
    float spotCutoff; // (range: [0.0,90.0], 180.0)
    vec3 spotDirection;
    float constantAttenuation;
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
};
uniform LightSourceParameters LightSource[numLights];

struct MaterialParameters {
    vec4 emission;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
    bool hasDiffuseTexture;
    bool hasSpecularTexture;
    bool hasEmissionTexture;
    bool hasAmbientTexture;
    bool hasNormalTexture;

    sampler2D emissionTexture;

    sampler2D diffuseTexture;
    sampler2D specularTexture;

    sampler2D ambientTexture;
    sampler2D normalTexture;
};
uniform MaterialParameters Material;

precision lowp float;

varying vec2 varyingTextcood;
varying vec3 varyingNormalDirection;
varying vec3 varyingViewDirection;
varying vec3 outLightVector[numLights];

void main()
{
    vec3 normalDirection = normalize(varyingNormalDirection);
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(varyingViewDirection);
    vec3 lightDirection;
    float attenuation;
    // initialize total lighting with ambient lighting
    vec4 totalLighting;
    vec4 emissionTerm;
    if ((length(Material.emission) != 0.0) || (Material.hasEmissionTexture)) {
        /* El material tiene un termino emisivo, es decir, emite luz. Lo andimos al total de color calculado */
        if (!Material.hasEmissionTexture) {
            emissionTerm = Material.emission.rgba;
        }
        else {
            emissionTerm = texture2D(Material.emissionTexture, varyingTextcood).rgba;
        }
        if (emissionTerm.a > 0.0){
            totalLighting = emissionTerm;
        }
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < numLights; index++) // for all light sources
    {
        vec4 ambientalTerm;
        vec4 specularReflection;
        vec4 diffuseReflection;
        if (length(LightSource[index].ambient.rgb) > 0.0){
            // es luz ambiental
            if (Material.hasAmbientTexture){
                ambientalTerm = vec4(LightSource[index].ambient, 1.0) * texture2D(Material.ambientTexture, varyingTextcood);
            }
            else {
                ambientalTerm = vec4(LightSource[index].ambient, 1.0) * vec4(Material.ambient);
            }
            //totalLighting = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
        }
        else {
            if (0.0 == LightSource[index].position.w) // directional light?
            {
                attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
                lightDirection = normalize(outLightVector[index]);
            }
            else // point light or spotlight (or other kind of light)
            {
                vec3 positionToLightSource = outLightVector[index];
                float distance = length(positionToLightSource);
                lightDirection = normalize(positionToLightSource);
                attenuation = 1.0 / (LightSource[index].constantAttenuation
                + LightSource[index].linearAttenuation * distance
                + LightSource[index].quadraticAttenuation * distance * distance);
                if (LightSource[index].spotCutoff <= 90.0) // spotlight?
                {
                    float clampedCosine = max(0.0, dot(-lightDirection, normalize(LightSource[index].spotDirection)));
                    if (clampedCosine < cos(radians(LightSource[index].spotCutoff))) // outside of spotlight cone?
                    {
                        attenuation = 0.0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attenuation = attenuation * pow(clampedCosine, LightSource[index].spotExponent);
                    }
                }
            }
            vec4 diffuseTerm;
            if (Material.hasDiffuseTexture){
                diffuseTerm = texture2D(Material.diffuseTexture,varyingTextcood);
            }
            else {
                diffuseTerm = Material.diffuse;
            }
            if (diffuseTerm.a > 0.0){
                diffuseReflection = attenuation
                * vec4(LightSource[index].lightColor, 1.0) * diffuseTerm
                * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
            }
            if (dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0) // light source on the wrong side?
            {
                specularReflection = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // no specular reflection
            }
            else // light source on the right side
            {
                vec4 specularTerm;
                if (Material.hasSpecularTexture){
                    specularTerm = texture2D(Material.specularTexture,varyingTextcood);
                }
                else {
                    specularTerm = Material.specular;
                }
                if (specularTerm.a > 0.0){
                    /* OPCION SIN HALFVECTOR
                    specularReflection = attenuation * vec4(LightSource[index].lightColor,1.0) * specularTerm
                    * pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), viewDirection)), Material.shininess);
                    */
                    // OPCION CON HALFVECTOR
                    vec3 light_half_vector = normalize(outLightVector[index] + viewDirection);
                    specularReflection = attenuation * vec4(LightSource[index].lightColor,1.0) * specularTerm
                    * pow(max(dot(light_half_vector, normalDirection), 0.0), Material.shininess);
                }
            }
        }
        totalLighting = totalLighting + ambientalTerm + diffuseReflection + specularReflection;
    }
    gl_FragColor = clamp(totalLighting, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Well, inside the main function, if we look at the foor loop, we have this line:

```
if (length(LightSource[index].ambient.rgb) > 0.0){
```

I found that debbuging with my Moto G, the shader always enter inside this statement, no matter that the scene hasn't an ambient light source. I can test this easyly writing totalLighting = vec4(1.0) inside the if branch.

This is not happening in the Adreno Profiler. I can't understand what's wrong because the profiler connects to the Moto G GPU and retrieves all the uniforms value, and ambient is a vec3 of 0.0 values. Even if I take a screen capture of the same device in the profiler I get the expected lighting behaviour in the profiler and a wrong behaviour in the phone. Shouldn't it be the same in both sites if they are connected?

As a curiosity, if I change the order of the declarations inside the LightSourceParameters I get very diferent results, and I can't understand why. For example, take a look at he screen capture I upload, all the scene gets red that is the color I'm using to clear the screen when the scene has been rendered with

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It's red for debbuging prupourses.

This is the original image in the moto g phone, in the usual declaration of the uniforms I have:

[image: Rendering in the moto g phone]

The next one is the capture I get if I move the vec3 ambient declaration to the end of the LightSourceParameter struct:

[image: Rendering in the phone moving the ambient light declaration to the end of the LightSourceParameters struct]

And this is the profiler capture where you can see the value of the uniform. Doesn't matter if the ambient declaration is at the begining of the struct or the end, the result is the same, as I would expect in the phone:

[image: Scene rendered through the Adreno profiler]

Does somebody knows what is wrong here or what I'm missunderstanding ?

Edit 1:

Commenting out the if statement of the ambient light:

```
//if (0.0 < length(LightSource[index].ambient)){
```

I allow the flow to go ahead and calculate the diffuse and specular light/material data. This is not optimal, but it´s a way to debug so I´m going to use it for now. The scene keeps black except the yellow sun rays (like the first image) until I substitute the light color in the diffuse calculation with a vec3(1.0) in this way:

```
       /*
            diffuseReflection = attenuation
                        * vec4(LightSource[index].lightColor, 1.0) * diffuseTerm
                        * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
        */
            diffuseReflection = attenuation
                        * vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0) * diffuseTerm
                        * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
```

This way the diffuse term is calculated as if It was being done in the Adreno profiler and the image is rendered well. So my supossition is that the full array of light struct has garbage in it or wrong data, but I cant understand why this is only happening in the moto g.

Comment: hey are you setting alpha value ?

Comment: cause we had same issue with alpha value.. we were assuming it will take default value

Comment: and sometimes in moto g default values as 0 it was taking.

Comment: I suppouse the alpha value is being set through the texture2d call. If the material hasn't an associated texture, usually his alpha channel is being set to 0.0. Anyway I have tested that the flow is entering into the if(length(ambient)) statement

Comment: And when entering into the if ambient statement, no more light calculation is made (thats because the scene is black if not moving the ambient declaration)

Comment: just check once properly.. because we had same issue.. in moto g.. it used to give black screen sometimes.. cause we were not passing alpha value externally

Comment: Thanks @PreethiRao, I remember to have this kind of problems in the past with this same phone, and I solved it the way you say, setting the alpha channel, but it looks not to be the problem now.